# How swift protocol Identifiable's @available working

Tags: swift, protocols

**protocol Identifiable is defined available above iOS 13 in Swift > Misc**

```swift
/// A class of types whose instances hold the value of an entity with stable identity.
@available(OSX 10.15, iOS 13, tvOS 13, watchOS 6, *)
public protocol Identifiable {

    /// A type representing the stable identity of the entity associated with `self`.
    associatedtype ID : Hashable

    /// The stable identity of the entity associated with `self`.
    var id: Self.ID { get }
}

@available(OSX 10.15, iOS 13, tvOS 13, watchOS 6, *)
extension Identifiable where Self : AnyObject {

    /// The stable identity of the entity associated with `self`.
    public var id: ObjectIdentifier { get }
}
```

But when I setup deployment target to under iOS 13.0 ex) below 11.0
there are not any compile error occur.

```swift
struct People: Identifiable {
    var id: String {
        return ""
    }
}

let people = People()
print(people.id) // There are no compile error
```

**Question is How Swift.Identifiable's @available annotation working?**

Answer (score 3):

You can declare an object as conforming to a protocol even if you support iOS versions that don't have that protocol, you just won't be able to use that protocol conformance in those versions.

For example, you would not be able to do this: `people as? Identifiable` without wrapping it in a `#available` block.

You can access `people.id` without a compiler error because it's just a regular `String` property that is still part of your struct even without the `Identifiable` conformance.

If your object was declared as a class and was relying on the default `id` property that it gets from the protocol conformance then you wouldn't be able to access the `id` property without an availability check:

```
class People: Identifiable {

}

let people = People()
print(people.id) // compiler error outside of #available check
```

Answer (score -1):

For the latest xcode 12.5 and iOS 14.5 has the same issue.

It has a fix in 10.5.2 version

just update your podfile with: **pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 10.5.2'**